# ThinkServer TS140 no POST (2 beeps) after BIOS upgrade

Tags: boot, bios, post, lenovo-desktop-computer

Yesterday I was experiencing a weird issue with Windows 10; the computer was outputting weird beeps (in Win10, **not** the BIOS) at random intervals.
It sounded like Morse Code, to be completely honest.

After some reading online, it was suggested that I update drivers.
After downloading the latest drivers for the system, a BIOS update was included.

I downloaded said BIOS update and installed it. The installation went fine, however now the system won't POST. The system now beeps twice on boor (after an extended period).

I've found the [following document](https://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1033391976.pdf) which provides instructions for recovering a failed BIOS.
So far the recovery has run through twice (if the system shuts down, the recovery was "successful").
The first time, I tried a new BIOS version, dated 2019. The system failed to POST. The second attempt was with a BIOS version from 2016 and the system still fails to POST.

Currently I'm at my whit's end. I need this system to run again.

More links where I've followed the instructions:

- [forums.lenovo.com](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkServer/TS-140-post-and-BIOS-disk/td-p/3876543)
- [Lenovo Downloads site](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ee/en/downloads/ds036977)

**EDIT: The answers in the question marked do not help this problem in the slightest.**

As I've mentioned, the problem is with the BIOS. Not the RAM, not the HDD, not anything.
I've attempted disconnecting and re-seating the memory, I've tried recovering the BIOS all to no end.

Is there another way the BIOS can be restored?

Comment: I never expected removing the DIMMs to reset the BIOS.
Rather, as I mentioned in the questions, I followed the instructions provided in the Lenovo HW guide. 

This involves re-setting the CMOS_RESET jumper from pins 1/2 to 2/3 and inserting a USB stick or optical disc and waiting for the system to copy the new BIOS in to its flash memory. 

I'm fully aware that the non-POSTing is telling me something, I'm curious to know if anyone has any inside knowledge, possibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just faced a similar issue. After many trying many things, it is working again.

Steps that worked:

1. Follow CLR_CMOS recovery instructions using ROM of the oldest BIOS available in Lenovo site
2. After a succesful BIOS recovery, boot with a USB keyboard in one of the rear ports (not in the front)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll mark it as such so it can help others.
Sadly, my Server died and I ended up replacing it w/ a new AMD board and chip.